# How to tell JSF to recognize primitive datatypes?

Tags: jsf, javabeans, primitive-types

I am writing a simple webpage with EJB and JSF. For my webpresentation I need a page with inputFields and checkboxes. 
In order to get the input from my webpage into a javaclass I need to configure my faces-config.xml file.
Here comes my problem: The checkboxes produce boolean values. Boolean is a primitive datatype. In my javaclass I would define primitives in such a manner

```
    private boolean checkBox1;
    private boolean checkBox2;
```

But my faces-config.xml does not recognize this datatype. It wants me to define it via java.lang.Boolean. If i do that everything is fine but it feels wrong to have code like this in any javaclass:

```
    private java.lang.Boolean checkBox1;
    private java.lang.Boolean checkBox2;
```

Is there any way to "teach" faces-config.xml what primitives are? :)

Comment: *"In order to get the input from my webpage into a javaclass I need to configure my faces-config.xml file"* This shouldn't be necessary. Where are you learning JSF? Are you really fiddling with managed properties in `faces-config.xml` instead of actually binding input component values to bean properties as shown in chapter 1 of a sane JSF tutorial?

Comment: @BalusC ahm... seems to be so ^^. I made a tutorial where they used the  graphical editor of the faces-config.xml. There they created the managed Beans and there they defined all of the attributes of these beans. I was able to acces these attributes within my JSF pages. I assumed this was the way to do stuff. If this is not what you were talking about than I probably found the only insane tutorial in the internet and would appriciate further advise or a link to a sane tutorial :D

Comment: Do not drag'n'drop code as long as you're unable to write the generated code yourself. Just write code from beginning on. You learn nothing about programming by using a visual editor. Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info I also strongly suspect that you were reading a JSF 1.x tutorial, possibly targeted at Netbeans+Woodstock. Don't do that. Head to JSF 2.x resources. JSF 2.0 was released almost 4 years ago already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *In order to get the input from my webpage into a javaclass I need to configure my faces-config.xml file*

This isn't making any sense. Just bind the component's value to the bean property directly. The following works just fine for me without any `faces-config.xml` registration (JSF 2.x assumed):

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.checked}" />
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
</h:form>
```

with

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {

    private boolean checked;

    public void submit() {
        System.out.println(checked);
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return true;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
    }

}
```

---

> *I made a tutorial where they used the graphical editor of the faces-config.xml*

Don't use a graphical editor. Don't drag'n'drop code. You won't learn writing code this way. Just write code yourself. You can however use shortcuts/wizards to autogenerate getters/setters and likes. But with that, you should still be sitting in a textbased editor.